# Changing the data on the table by selecting from the drop down menu on SHINY

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

Im having an issue with making the data on my table change every time I choose a different inventory product from the drop menu. Should I make it a reactive table? If so how should I do that? Im uncertain how to proceed.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Clothes Inventory"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "CurrentInventory",  
      label = "1. Select Inventory Product",  
      choices = unique(df$CurrentInventory), selected = "Blouse"),
     dateRangeInput("dates", 
                     "2. Enter date range",
                     start = min(df$firstInventory), 
                     end = max(df$latestInventory))),
      textOutput("DateRange")
      ),
      
    textInput(inputId = "text", 
      label = "3. Enter Notes Here", ""),
    
  mainPanel(ui <- 
                            textOutput("mytext"),
                                                    
                             tableOutput("mytable")
                             
                             )
      )
    

server <- function(input, output, session) {


output$mytext <- renderText(input$text)


                                   
datasetInput1 <- renderTable({
    df %>% filter(currentInventory == input$CurrentInventory)
  })
                                   
output$mytable <- renderTable(df)
   
                                   
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `output$myTable` doesn't know that `input$CurrentInventory` has changed. If you just put the filtering in the `output$myTable` then it will work. See the example with reduced code for simplicity.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(CurrentInventory = c("Blouse","Blouse","Shirt","Tie"),
                 colB = c("A","B","A","A"),
                 colC = 1:4)

ui <- basicPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "CurrentInventory",  
                label = "1. Select Inventory Product",  
                choices = unique(df$CurrentInventory), 
                selected = "Blouse"),
    tableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$mytable <- renderTable(
    df %>% filter(CurrentInventory == input$CurrentInventory)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```